# Best practice for storing custom value instead of foreignkey?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

The situation is quite simple.

```
class EventType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    event_type = models.ForeignKey('EventType')
```

There is need to give an opportunity to enter **custom** `event_type` in `CharField`. The reason why `EventType` class is separate is that there will be a lor of lookups on that field. And lookups will be **ONLY** on ForeignKey entries (Not the custom values).

**To sum up:** Is there a better solution to store custom `event_type` than declaring an aditional field `custom_event_type = models.CharField()`?

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking about... is there anything stopping you just creating a new event type as needed?..

Comment: @Sayse there is nothing that stops from creating, i thought that creating additional objects would mess with lookup time, but i think suggested answer make the trick.

Comment: I disagree, but then I don't see how an extra booleanfield even applies to the question as I understand it.

Comment: @Sayse the question was about the efficient way for choosing from the proposed `EventType` objects or provide custom one, in each case the information need to be stored but without much impact on lookups' speed. And on the search page the main(not custom ones) `EventType`s need to be listed, that's how additional boolean field is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could still save all event types with the same model, but use an additional field to tell whether you want to include an `EventType` in your search results:

```
class EventType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    include_in_search = models.BooleanField()

class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    event_type = models.ForeignKey('EventType')
```

If you create a database index sorted by `include_in_search` and then by `name`, I bet you really won't notice any difference in the time to make a lookup.

You did not write all the specifications you need, but you may want to set the `name` field to be unique or even use it as primary key.